# Pretty print in Hy?

Tags: hy

Is there something like `pprint` or `clojure.pprint/pprint` available in Hy? More specific, is there something that would convert something like this:

```
{:a {:a 0 :b 1 :c 2 :d 3 :e 4} :b {:a 0 :b 1 :c 2 :d 3 :e 4} :c {:a 0 :b 1 :c 2 :d 3 :e 4} :d {:a 0 :b 1 :c 2 :d 3 :e 4} :e {:a 0 :b 1 :c 2 :d 3 :e 4}}
```

In this (this is an example, doesn't need to be exactly like below):

```
{:e {:e 4 :d 3 :c 2 :b 1 :a 0}
 :d {:e 4 :d 3 :c 2 :b 1 :a 0}
 :c {:e 4 :d 3 :c 2 :b 1 :a 0}
 :b {:e 4 :d 3 :c 2 :b 1 :a 0}
 :a {:e 4 :d 3 :c 2 :b 1 :a 0}}
```

I already tried `hy-repr` and `hydiomatic.utils/hypprint`, however `hy-repr` didn't seem to pretty print long maps and hydiomatic does not work in recent versions of Hy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Feel free to file an issue requesting it. However, our Emacs package, `hy-mode`, does have some auto-indent features (partly borrowed from Emacs's generic Lisp-editing code), and probably the Vim plugin does too, but that's been less actively maintained (to nobody's surprise, Lispers tend to prefer Emacs).

Comment: Well, my use case is to print native Clojure data structures (i.e.: EDN or Clojure code) in a CLI, so I needed something in either Hy or Python itself.

Thanks, I will open a issue for it.